# Django migrations Many2Many Through model, ValueError: Cannot alter field

Tags: django, django-migrations, manytomanyfield

Hey guys I want to sort my many to many field and in that case I want to `through`. My code look something like this:

```
class SkirunRatePoint(models.Model):
    latitude = models.DecimalField(u'lat', max_digits=10, decimal_places=6)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(u'lng', max_digits=10, decimal_places=6)
    elevation = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(u'Name', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Point'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Points'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode('{0} / {1}'.format(self.latitude, self.longitude))

class SkirunRoute(models.Model):
    skirun = models.ForeignKey(Skirun, verbose_name=u'Path')
    ratepoints = models.ManyToManyField(
    SkirunRatePoint,
    through="SkirunRatePointThrough",
    verbose_name=u'Points',
    blank=True,
)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = u'trasy z punktami'
        def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.skirun)

class SkirunRatePointThrough(models.Model):
     skirunroute = models.ForeignKey(SkirunRoute, related_name="skirun_route")
     skirunratepoint = models.ForeignKey(SkirunRatePoint, related_name="skirun_rate_points")

     order = models.IntegerField(
         blank=True,
         null=True,
     )
```

Don't mind about indents, they are find on my pc.

Makemigrations is going fine, but when I try to migrate it throws me an error which says:

`ValueError: Cannot alter field skirun.SkirunRoute.ratepoints into skirun.SkirunRoute.ratepoints - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields)`

Any ideas what might be the problem ?

Comment: There is a single quote `'` missing in your first field (`latitude`).

Comment: Nope it's just an error in pasting code.

Comment: As it says: you cannot add a `through` model to an existing m2m field. You can remove the field and add it again, this time _with_ the `through` model, but you will lose some data.

Comment: knbk is more or less right, but you can just use SeparateDatabaseAndState to change to the through model and then you will loose no data (don't forget to write a CreateModel for the new model though -- but just as state). Add the order in a new migration.

Comment: Ok, it really hellped me. So it's now solved.